# Removal of the incoming sms

Tags: android, sms

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            if (msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals(
                    SmsModuleActivity.number))
                deleteMessage(context, msgs[i]);
        }
    }
}

private void deleteMessage(Context context, SmsMessage msg) {
    Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/");
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(deleteUri, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        try {
            String pid = c.getString(0);
            String uri = "content://sms/inbox/" + pid;
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("read", true);
            context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse(uri), values,
                    null, null);
            context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

New incoming sms not removed. When I get sms from this number it delete only old sms from this sender, but no new message. I need delete new incoming message from specific number (see source code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `abortBroadcast()` in place of `deleteMessage(context, msgs[i])` which will stop the incoming sms to reach inbox and you don't need to delete it then.

Comment: No, I need delete NEW incoming sms. But it not removed, it removes only old sms from this number.

Comment: Some effect as in first post.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), "_id="+id, null);
```

Comment: Some effect as in first post.

Comment: It's not delete new incoming sms :(

Comment: Use BroadcastReceiver for deleting incoming message.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code to delete last sms after recieving sms in your first activity class. Dont forget 
togive sms read and write permission in your mainfest file.

```
  Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address","person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

                    long id = c.getLong(0);
                    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);

            }`enter code here`
```